# Collectionview with multiple fullscreen sections and horizontal paging

Tags: pagination, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

I am trying to create a collectionview with multiple sections. Each section is full screen and has multiple cells. I am using UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout. The collectionview has horizontal paging where you can scroll from section to section horizontally. Each section has a header with label. I am having a problem with the position of the cells in each section. For each section, I need the cells to be right below the section header.

[image]

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class SetupProfileController:UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    
    
    var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    let colors = [UIColor.red, UIColor.blue, UIColor.green, UIColor.orange, UIColor.purple, UIColor.red, UIColor.blue, UIColor.green, UIColor.orange, UIColor.purple]

    let data:[String:[String]] = [
        "Section 1":["One","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six"],
        "Section 2":["Astrology","Engineers|Scientists","SoftwareDevelopers","Mathematicians","Physicists","ArtificialIntelligence","ComputerVision",
                "Filmmaking","VisualArtists","Animators","Singers","SongWriters","Rappers","AfroBeats","MusicProducers","FashionDesigners","Chefs|Cooks","Drag","Performers","Dancers","Musicians","Music","MusicProducers","Animators","AnimalRightsActivists","TransMen","TransWomen","Nonbinary","Women","Men","PhDs","History","StartUps","MentalHealth","PhysicalFitness","LanguageLearning","AsylumSeekers","Environmentalism","Veganism"]
        ]
    let sections = ["Section 1","Section 2"]
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        print("COLLECTIONVIEW")
        let layout = makeLayout()
        //self.collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height), collectionViewLayout: layout)
        self.collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect.zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        //collectionView.isScrollEnabled = true
        self.collectionView.register(SetupProfileTitleHeader.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: "header", withReuseIdentifier: "SetupProfileTitleHeader")
        
        self.collectionView.register(CollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell")
        
        self.collectionView.delegate = self
        self.collectionView.dataSource = self

        self.collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(self.collectionView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            self.collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor),
            self.collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor),
            self.collectionView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor),
            self.collectionView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor)
            ])
         
        
        
        
        collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
        
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return sections.count
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        return data[sections[section]]!.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        //cell.backgroundColor = colors[indexPath.item]
        cell.backgroundColor = .red
        cell.textLabel.text = data[sections[indexPath.section]]![indexPath.item]
        return cell
    }
    
    func makeLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
        //let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { (section: Int, environment: NSCollectionLayoutEnvironment) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection? in
            let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(sectionProvider: { (sectionIndex, environment) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection? in
                
            let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .estimated(80), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0))
            let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
            //item.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 10, leading: 10, bottom: 10, trailing: 10)
            let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .absolute(40))
            let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [item])
            group.interItemSpacing = NSCollectionLayoutSpacing.fixed(CGFloat(10))
            
            let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
            section.interGroupSpacing = CGFloat(10.0)
            section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .groupPagingCentered
            //section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .continuous
            section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 20, bottom: 0, trailing: 20)
        
            
             let height = CGFloat(40)
            let headerItemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension:.estimated(80) )
            let headerItem = NSCollectionLayoutBoundarySupplementaryItem(layoutSize: headerItemSize, elementKind: "header", alignment: .top)
            section.boundarySupplementaryItems = [headerItem]
            
            return section
        })
        let config = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayoutConfiguration()
        config.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        config.interSectionSpacing = 0
        layout.configuration = config
        return layout
    }
    
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        guard let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "SetupProfileTitleHeader", for: indexPath) as? SetupProfileTitleHeader else {
            return SetupProfileTitleHeader()
        }

        
        headerView.titleLabel.text = "Section \(indexPath.section + 1)" //keys[indexPath.section]//"Section \(indexPath.section + 1)"
        headerView.backgroundColor = .blue
        return headerView
    }
    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting:

```
section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .groupPaging
```

Instead of:

```
.groupPagingCentered
```

Seems to have fixed the issue.

Also add:

```
section.supplementariesFollowContentInsets = false
```

in case you are having problems with the section header overlapping with the cells